# configurar SLF4J com log4j

Tags: log, log4j

Estou com um problema um tanto confuso mas vou tentar explicar, estou trabalhando em um projeto que esta usando algumas bibliotecas externas, e gostaria de implementar um log, já vi que nos pacotes externos eles usam o pacote SLF4J. Então fiz um projeto para testar configurações do componente para gravar em um arquivo e estava indo tudo certo, até eu tentar por o SLF4J no projeto que estou trabalhando, porque quando configurei o log4j no projeto aparentemente ele ativou todas as chamadas das bibliotecas externas e começou a mostrar tudo no console, sendo que não gravou nada no arquivo de log, aparentemente ele ignora o arquivo de configuração, mas ao mesmo tempo isso não é verdade porque quando o tiro tudo para.

O projeto é um console e não usa mavem, por problemas de configuração de rede aqui no trabalho. O que eu quero é que ele grave o log no arquivo e de preferencia sem as informações das bibliotecas externas, mas se não for possível tudo bem pode logar tudo. Abaixo segue o arquivo de log4j.xml com as informações sensíveis alteradas.

O projeto me apresenta o seguinte warn "Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings", mas tudo que vi até agora tinha haver com a configuração de mais de uma dependência no Maven, mas como já disse não estou usando Maven.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <param name="threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 
  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"> 
     <param name="file" value="d:/temp/app.log" />
     <param name="append" value="true" />
     <param name="threshold" value="WARN" />
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
     </layout>
  </appender> 
   <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="file" /> 
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, após muita pesquisa encontrei o problema, basicamente um dos pacotes de terceiros que estou usando, usou o SLF4J e distribui o JAR com o slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar, então quando configurei o o LOG4J na aplicação que estamos construindo, ele encontrava a outra implementação de exemplo primeiro e ignorava o resto. O que fiz foi abrir este pacote, tirar a outra implementação ficando assim, somente a implementação concreta do LOG4J.  Pelo que entendi esta falha pode acontecer sempre que tiver mais de uma implementação concreta de log sendo usada com o SLF4J.